# DBeaver PostgreSQL Array of Foreign Keys

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

For a homework assignment, I have downloaded the [imdb data set](https://datasets.imdbws.com/) and am importing it into new tables in PostgreSQL using DBeaver.  Some of the tables have arrays of foreign keys.  For example,

name.basics table contains information about actors

```
nconst  primaryName birthYear   deathYear   primaryProfession   knownForTitles
nm0000001   Fred Astaire    1899    1987    soundtrack,actor,miscellaneous  tt0027125,tt0053137,tt0050419,tt0072308
```

In the above, the knownForTitles field references primary keys in the title.basics table, which lists information about movies.

```
tconst  titleType   primaryTitle    originalTitle   isAdult startYear   endYear runtimeMinutes  genres
tt0000001   short   Carmencita  Carmencita  0   1894    \N  1   Documentary,Short
```

Am I able to create an array of foreign keys in name.basics in the knownForTitles field that points back to the title.basics primary key column?  I've tried setting up a column with an array of varchars pointing back to the title.basics primary key but get this error:

Detail: Key columns "knownfortitles" and "tconst" are of incompatible types: character varying[] and character varying.

I've invested significant time researching this and understand it is possible in some DBMS, such as MongoDB, to use arrays of foreign keys.  My question is whether it can feasibly be implemented in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: Clearly your error(s) & goal can be expected to be faqs. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using arrays of identifiers, you cannot have foreign key constraints in PostgreSQL. There has been [a patch to implement that](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/4EB3DF02.4020604%402ndQuadrant.it), but that was never applied.

Using arrays in that fashion will not only prevent you from getting referential integrity, it will also make joins complicated and slow. You should avoid such data models.